# Convert floppy image from 1,44 mb to 720 k

Tags: images, floppy

The other day I found an old floppy from the 80's.
I inserted it in my USB floppy drive and I got a message from Microsoft security essentials that the disk was infected by a boot virus.

I supposed that a modern AV couldn't fix such an old virus, so, before pressing "fix the problem" I made a disk image with [RawwriteWin](http://www.chrysocome.net/rawwrite).

MSE "fixed" the virus with a full drive format. Shoot.

I told myself: "who cares, I have the full image"

Then I noticed my disk was a 720k disk, and rawwritewin only makes 1.44 images (I have a 1.44 mb image)

Rewriting the image on the disk fails.

Reading the image with dosbox fails.

Reading the image with virtualbox fails.

With an hex editor I can see that my middle school data is still in the image, why I can't mount it? It's because it's too big? If I reduce the size to 720k trimming the file, will it work?

Edit: just did `split -b 737280 myimage.img out` but dosbox still can't open this image... (can open, but shows empty and with 2 tb free size)

Comment: You could try running a DOS VM with its floppy disc mapped to the image file.

Comment: No, tried in virtualbox+freedos, the virtual image is unreadable

Comment: All I can now suggest is: 1. Maybe the formatting only deleted the partition or directory structure: if so a partition or file recovery program might find and extract files from the floppy. 2. Have a look at the created image with a hex lister to see if there are periodic blocks of zeroes, indicating that each read was half the expected length, but the full length was written: if so a 10-line C program could make a corrected image which would be mountable in the DOS box. 3. Try a repair CD: if a Windows disc like UBCD4Win doesn't help, try a Linux-based disc or even a try/install Live CD.

Comment: the image looks fine in an hex editor... http://imgur.com/nh6ZvVP

Comment: If the image is correct for the first 720KB, then the Linux **dd** program will do a raw write for you and you should get your floppy back (but try it on a blank floppy, in case you want to try to recover files from the formatted one). You can copy the 1.44MB file and leave **dd** to error when it has filled the floppy: it will still have written everything.

Comment: try the [testdisk utility](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) which can scan for fat tables and recover files

Answer (score 0):

try either [WinImage](http://www.winimage.com/download/winima90.exe) or a linux distro maybe a live CD/DVD or virtual machine.

Comment: i'll try to download winimage